# How to communicate between pods in a service?

Tags: kubernetes

Suppose I have a service containing two pods. One of the pods is an HTTP server, and the other pod needs to hit a REST endpoint on this pod. Is there a hostname that the second pod can use to address the first pod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "service" you aren't referring to the Kubernetes lexicon of a `Service` object, otherwise your two Pods in the `Service` would be identical, so let's start by teasing out what a "Service" means in Kubernetes land.

You will have to create an additional [Kubernetes object called a `Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to get your hostname for your HTTP server's `Pod`. When you create a `Service` you will define a `.spec.selector` that points to a set of labels on the HTTP service's Pod. For the sake of example, let's say the label is `app: nginx`. The name of that `Service` object will become the internal DNS record that can be queried by the second `Pod`.

A simplified example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: http-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-http-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Now your second `Pod` can make requests to the HTTP service by the `Service` name, `my-http-service`.

It's also worth mentioning that Kubernetes best practice dictates that these `Pod`s be managed by controllers such as [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)s or [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/)s for all sorts of reasons, including high availability of your applications.

Comment: Great! do you have an idée on how to change the destination dynamically, i.e the first will communicate with an other new deployed pod, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that a **service** is a different concept in Docker then in K8s. The easiest way of getting what you want would be creating the two pods; say `pod-1` and `pod-2`, with a yaml file similar to this one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: NAME
  labels:
    app: LABEL
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Say NAME and LABEL are `nginx` and `nginx-1`, so you have now two pods called `nginx` and `nginx-1`, with labels `app: nginx` and `app: nginx-1`. Actually, as only one of them is going to be exposed, the other label is irrelevant.

Now you expose the pod either with a yaml file or from command line.

**Yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

**Command line:**

`kubectl expose pod nginx --port 80 --name server`

If you now access the second pod (nginx-1) and `curl` the service directly, you would end up hitting the pod behind it (nginx):

```
nerus:~/workspace $ kubectl exec -it nginx-1 bash 
root@nginx-1:/# curl -I server 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your pod **kubectl expose deployment  --type=name of pod** , then you can use the **kubectl describe**  It will show you **port** number . Then you access you pod at **http://localhost:portnumber in last command** ....**.....Hope it will help .

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, you answered your own question: a `Service` is a stable name and IP that abstracts over the individual coming-and-going of the `Pod`s to which it will route traffic, as described very well in [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

If `the-http-pod` needs to reach `the-rest-pod`, then create a `Service` that matches the labels on the `PodSpec` that created `the-rest-pod`, and from that point forward `the-http-pod` can always use `${serviceName}.${serviceNamespace}.svc.cluster.local` to each any Pod that has matching labels